When using langsci-gb4e the font size decreases at the glt line. All the following text is also decreased. Is there any way to stop this?
Here is the entire code:
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{kotex}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{langsci-gb4e}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat} %This seems to be necessary with covington
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
%\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage{comment}


%This block of commented code translates default words to Spanish
%-------------------------------------------------------------
%\pointpoints{punto\\puntos}
%\bonuspointpoints{punto extra\\puntos extra}

%\totalformat{Pregunta \thequestion: \totalpoints{} puntos}

%\chqword{Pregunta}
%\chpgword{Página}
%\chpword{Puntos}
%\chbpword{Puntos extra}
%\chsword{Puntos obtenidos}
%\chtword{Total}

%\boxedpoints
%-------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
%This code creates the text before the first question
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\large
\begin{center}
%\fbox{\fbox{\parbox{5.5in\\\centering
ENG3306\\
기말시험지\\
2024년12월18일\\
75 분\\
%Submit all files named using the following format: 20209999김철수Q1a.doc(x) or G20209999MarySmithQ2.pdf.
Answer questions 1 and 3-6 on the exam answer sheets (시험답안지) provided. Answer question 2 on these question sheets. To avoid unnecessarily killing trees, use both sides of the answer sheets. 나무를 아무 이유없이 죽이지 맙시다. 답안지의 앞뒷면을 모두 사용해 주시기 바랍니다.
%}}}
\end{center}

\vspace{5mm}

\makebox[\textwidth]{Name (한글):\enspace\hrulefill}

\vspace{5mm}

\makebox[\textwidth]{Name (English):\enspace\hrulefill}

\vspace{5mm}

\makebox[\textwidth]{Student Number 학번:\enspace\hrulefill}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------

\bigskip

\centering
\begin{center}
%\combinedgradetable[h][questions]
\gradetable[v][questions]
\end{center}

%\newpage

%\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{IPA_Kiel_2020_full_600.png}

\newpage
%Here, the questions begin
\begin{questions}

%First question below
\question Draw trees for the following sentences. If any sentence is ambiguous draw trees for both sentences and give unambiguous paraphrases. Triangles may be used for names of people and cities.

%This question has several parts
\begin{parts}

\part[10] The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. 
\vspace{5mm} 

\part[10] Draw a tree for \textbf{\textit{one}} of the following sentences. Please choose only ONE sentence (Korean, French, or Irish) and draw a tree for it. 

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Use triangles for DPs in the Korean sentence. Assume that 만들어지 (manduleci `make.\textsc{pass}' is a V.)\\
    \glll 민수가 사과를 먹었다.\\
    Minswu-ka sakwa-lul mek-ess-ta\\
    Minsoo-\textsc{nom} apple-\textsc{acc} eat-\textsc{pst-decl}\\
    \glt `Minsoo ate an apple.'
    \item French (The hyphen between \textit{penses} and \textit{tu} is an orthographic convention of French. Treat them as two separate words.)\\
    \gll Voici une phrase.\\
    here a sentence\\
    \glt `Here is a sentence.'
    \item Irish: Use a triangle for proper nouns, but do not use triangles for any other DPs. Assume the pronoun \textit{sé} is a D. \\
    \gll Hello\\
    hello\\
    \glt `Hello.'
\end{enumerate}

\end{parts}

\droptotalpoints %Prints the number of points in this question

%\vspace{5mm}
\newpage

\end{questions}

\end{document}



Note that your code in the question could have been more minimal, by removing all packages and body text that are not related to the sentences and glosses. If you had done this then you would probably also have identified the issue, because the occurrence of \large was in a part of the code that would have been removed while minimizing.

The \glt command calls \transfont, which is defined as \newcommand{\transfont}{\normalsize\upshape}, so normal size. However, in your document at the start you set \large. So everything up to the first \glt is large, and after that it is normal size (which is smaller than large).
The solution therefore is to either not set \large (or set it in a more restricted scope, for example inside of \begin{center}), or redefine \transfont such that it is also large.
Code snippet for setting \large inside of the center environment:
\begin{center}
\large
%\fbox{\fbox{\parbox{5.5in\\\centering
ENG3306\\
기말시험지\\
2024년12월18일\\
75 분\\
%Submit all files named using the following format: 20209999김철수Q1a.doc(x) or G20209999MarySmithQ2.pdf.
Answer questions 1 and 3-6 on the exam answer sheets (시험답안지) provided. Answer question 2 on these question sheets. To avoid unnecessarily killing trees, use both sides of the answer sheets. 나무를 아무 이유없이 죽이지 맙시다. 답안지의 앞뒷면을 모두 사용해 주시기 바랍니다.
%}}}
\end{center}

Result:

Alternatively, redefine \transfont, with \large in global scope:
\usepackage{langsci-gb4e}
\renewcommand{\transfont}{\large\upshape}
% ...
\begin{document}
%This code creates the text before the first question
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\large
\begin{center}
%\fbox{\fbox{\parbox{5.5in\\\centering
ENG3306\\
기말시험지\\


Personally I think the first solution is preferred, the code is more clean and the text is somewhat more readable at normal size.

Thanks! Makes perfect sense.
